# Show swrevealviewcontroller over main view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

The default behavior(shadow) of swrevealviewcontroller makes it appear that the main view controller is on top of the menu. Is there a way to reverse the behavior so that the menu appears on top of the main view controller?

Answer (score 1):

SWRevealViewController doesn't have this behaviour.
But you can try this library that has what are you looking for: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu